# Django QuerySet union() is not giving the desired output

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have written the following code

views.py

```
room_list = Room.objects.all()
time_slot_list = TimeSlot.objects.none()
for room in room_list:
    time_slots = TimeSlot.objects.filter(room=room)
    for time_slot in time_slots:
        time_slot_list.union(time_slot)
print(time_slot_list)
```

models.py

```
class Room(models.Model):
    class Meta:
      ordering = ['number']
    number =  models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(550), MinValueValidator(1)],
        primary_key=True
        )
    CATEGORIES = (
        ('Regular', 'Regular'),
        ('Executive', 'Executive'),
        ('Deluxe', 'Deluxe'),
    )
    category = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=CATEGORIES, default='Regular')
    CAPACITY = (
        (1, '1'),
        (2, '2'),
        (3, '3'),
        (4, '4'),
    )
    capacity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=CAPACITY, default=2
        )
    advance = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=10)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

class TimeSlot(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['available_from']
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    available_from = models.TimeField()
    available_till = models.TimeField()
```

When I am printing `time_slot_list`, I am getting empty QuerySet but I want it to contain the list of timeslots.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if I remember well you have to add all=True:

```
time_slot_list.union(time_slot, all=True)
```

*The UNION operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate values, use the all=True argument.*

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#union

Answer (score 0):

`QuerySet` methods don't mutate the instance, so you need to reassign the result of `.union()` back to the variable.

Also, `.union()` accepts another `QuerySet` rather than a model object.

```py
# for time_slot in time_slots:                     # Change these
#     time_slot_list.union(time_slot)              #
time_slot_list = time_slot_list.union(time_slots)  # to this
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced you need `union` at all. You can here work with the [**`__in`** lookup <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
room_list = Room.objects.all()
time_slot_list = TimeSlot.objects.filter(room__in=room_list)
```